# compute percentile for categorical values in a list in python

Tags: python

I have list part_no which has the values as below.

```
[
  'KH661-05782',
  'ZD661-05428',
  'CH661-04581',
  '661-07970',
  '661-07299',
  'ZM661-01301',
  '661-07288',
  '661-02898',
  '661-04582',
  'KH661-05431',
  'CH661-04581',
  'SF661-07955',
  '661-04746'
]
```

I want to compute percentile for each value. So my output should look like
`[['ZD661-05428', 0.9545454545454546], ['CH661-04581', 0.045454545454545456]]`

But I get results like this:
`[['ZD661-05428', 2.9321729747481263e-06]]` for the code below:

```
vc =repair['PART_NO'].tolist()
count = len(vc) * 1.0

print [[x, vc.count(x) / count] for x in set(vc)]
```

Comment: Your expected output does not match the input you report.

Comment: @ScottHunter ['MY661-03509', 2.9321729747481263e-06],['661-7031', 1.4660864873740632e-05] is an example of the output

Comment: Compute expected output (not example) for the given input you posted and add to question.

Comment: When I take a column of a DataFrame and insert to a list using the code as below I get the following output:

Comment: @Austin I was under the impression that python lists maintain order but however my output is not the same as my input and I have no idea why

Comment: We know you didn't get the output you need. I was asking about expected output. How do you expect us to help (code) without any idea on what should be the output? BTW, python lists maintain order.

Comment: @Austin the problem here is I was using set(vc) so instead when I just used vc which was my list I got the desired output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print [[i, vc.count(i) / count] for i in vc]`

This solves the problem